# Data Types - The Real Basics

Tags: types, primitive-types

I would say I'm pretty new to this but could someone explain the basics about data types, more specifically Integers, characters, boolean, string and floating-point numbers.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide (links) of what you have read about the topic and explain what part(s) you did not understand. Also, is this a general programming question or have you a specific language in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types or datatypes say what kind of information you are able to store in a variable.

It is like you will assume that you have in your pocket a wallet with datatype "money", thus you are able store "money" there but not "keys".

Example datatypes:

---

Integer can store whole numbers:
5
12937
1298273

can't store number with fractional part:
123.43
234.534634643
12452352.1235

can't store strings:
"hello"
"nice to meet you"

---

floating point can store whole number and this with fractional part:
5
12937
1298273
123.43
234.534634643
12452352.1235

can't store strings:
"hello"
"nice to meet you"

---

Characters can store single chars:
"a"
"n"
"d"

can't store whole strings:
"hello"
"nice to meet you"

---

Boolean can store logical values, logical value answers the question if something is:
True 
False

Physically booleans can be represented in different wayy: True could be 1 or any value except 0 and False can be 0 (like in C like languages)

Answer (score 2):

The [Primitive data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_type) on Wikipedia seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

For which programming language? For Java, you can find a good introduction and overview in the lessons [Primitive Data Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [Numbers and Strings](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/index.html) of Sun's Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt someone will provide a good run down of these types however you could simply read this:-

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type